# Add options to a html <select> on content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

Noobie here... trying to figure out something. I'm working on this chrome extension and I injected some html on the page and the next step would be to read all the page finding some text and adding it as options on the select input fields I injected. This is part of my manifest:

```js
    "content_scripts" : [
        {
            "run_at": "document_end",
            "js" : [
                "js/main.js"
            ],
            "css" : [
                "css/main.css"
             ],               
            "matches" : ["https://streamyard.com/*"]
        }
```

this is my content script:

```js
var isHtmlDeployed = false;
var x=0;

//read the html file
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange; 
xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL('../includes/sceneSettings.html'), true);
xhr.send();
fillLayoutCombo();

//Inject the html file
function handleStateChange(){
    if (xhr.readyState=4 && xhr.responseText !='' &xhr.status==200 && isHtmlDeployed==false){
        var newHtml = document.createElement('div');
        newHtml.innerHTML = xhr.responseText; 
        document.body.appendChild (newHtml);
        isHtmlDeployed = true;  
    }
}

//add options 
function fillLayoutCombo(){ 
    for(var i=0;i<=9;i++){
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = 'Solo Layout';
        opt.innerHTML = 'Solo Layout';
        console.log('select[id="cboSceneType'+i+'"]');
        select = document.querySelector('[id="cboSceneType'+i+'"]');
        select.appendChild(opt);
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why when I get to fillLayoutCombo() function the html I injected is still not loaded so I end up select = document.querySelector('[id="cboSceneType'+i+'"]'); being null and get a error. Even with my manifest saying the script should run at the end of the page load. What can I do to fix this situation (while writting I just realized that 'document_end' is doing nothing after all the html will only be injected when the script run so am I having a problem with assynchronous xmlhttprequest? How to solve it?)

Thx for your help.

Comment: Is the website you're trying to inject this option onto loading DOM elements asynchronously? Maybe the page only loads when the JS gets run?

Comment: As much as I understand all the rest o the page is loaded. I can access any native website DOMElements.. just cant access my own injected at handleStateChange

Comment: I tried to add a listener to DOMContentLoad and it never triggers so I supposed it already happened

Comment: the thing with `DOMContentLoad` is it will only return on first time the DOMContent is loaded, it will not care about subsequent dom being added to the page.

Comment: before you try to append the element try this:

`console.log(document.body.innerHTML)` to see the state of the page.

Comment: I did check it manually. I put a break point and try to look for my html on the page. At the moment I'm trying to run fillLayoutCombo() my html is not injected yet. Thats why I think its problem with assychronous xmlhttprequest.

Comment: Ok I'm stupid lol. I just changed the call to fillLayoutCombo as the last step of handleStateChange... problem solved! Thx @mountaindrew sorry to bother you. One last question... how do I close this topic so it stays open?

Answer (score 0):

Just to set people in the solution. I just moved the  the call to fillLayoutCombo as the last step of handleStateChange.
Problem was solved

Thank you guys!